# Showing that an entire function is a polynomial based on its values on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f : {\bf C} \to {\bf C}$ be an entire function.

Assume that $|f(z)| = 1$ when $|z| = 1$.

**Is it true that we must have $f = z \mapsto C z^m$ where $m$ is an integer and $|C| = 1$ ?***

I think the answer is yes.
By maximum modulus, $f(z) \leq 1$ whenever $|z| \leq 1$.
Likely Cauchy's theorem can be applied here perhaps after applying a suitable Mobius transform.

Comment: It's the part in bold.